# OpenLayers Popup not showing. Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId(...) is null being encountered

Tags: openlayers, geojson, popup, react

I am using OpenLayers in React.js to render the results of a GeoJSON data.  The results should be shown in a Popup when a marker is clicked. I have been using Microsoft Bing to generate code as I am a beginner GIS web developer using OpenLayers and React.js.  I am encountering this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

The marker is correctly being shown but whenever I clicked it, the popup won't show and the error is displayed. The API call returned correctly the values however I cannot properly display it in a popup.  Please advise. Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import Style from "ol/style/Style";
import Icon from "ol/style/Icon";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import Overlay from "ol/Overlay";

const DataLayer = ({ map, layerType }) => {

  const [layers, setLayers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {

      if (layerType === 'fireIncident') {
        
        const res = await fetch(`/api/fire_incident`);
        const data = await res.json();
  
        if (data && data.length > 0 ) {
          const wktOptions = {
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
          }
          
          const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
            features: data.map((f) => new GeoJSON().readFeature(f, wktOptions)),
          });
  
          console.log('GeoJSON data:', data)

          // Fire marker
          const iconStyle = new Style({
            image: new Icon({
              anchor: [0.5, 45],
              anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
              anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
              src: 'fire.png'
            })
          })          

          const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: iconStyle
          });
  
          map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
          setLayers((layers) => [...layers, vectorLayer]);

          // Create Pop-up layer
          const popup = new Overlay({
            element: document.getElementById('popup')
          })

          map.addOverlay(popup);

          //Display pop
          map.on('click', function (event) {
            map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer){
              const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
              popup.setPosition(coordinates);

              const properties = feature.getProperties();
              document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = 
                'Incident year: ' + properties.incyr + '<br />' +
                'PENRO: ' + properties.penro + '<br />' +
                'CENRO: ' + properties.cenro + '<br />' +
                'Location: ' + properties.location;
            })
          })

        }
      }
    };
  
    fetchData();
    
  }, [map, layerType]);
  
    return null;

};
  
export default DataLayer;
```

Here is the results of the API call. It returned 2 results:

```
[{"properties":{"incyr":2019,"month":"February","penro":"PPG","cenro":"","location":"Brgy Diaz","occur_date":"2019-02-10T00:00:00.000Z","cause":2,"area_damage":1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[120.51350683576823,15.099785805351729]},"_id":"6547bc4174377cd1cbd44415","type":"Feature","__v":0},{"properties":{"incyr":2020,"month":"March","penro":"PPG","cenro":"","location":"San Vicente","occur_date":"2020-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","cause":1,"area_damage":0.5},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[120.73099597560082,15.233933632945224]},"_id":"6547bc6174377cd1cbd44417","type":"Feature","__v":0}]
```

BaseMap.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import 'ol/ol.css';

const BaseMap = ({ center, zoom, children }) => {
  const mapElement = useRef();
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current,
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat(center),
        zoom: zoom,
      }),
    });

    setMap(initialMap);
    return () => initialMap.setTarget(null);
  }, [center, zoom]);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="map" ref={mapElement} >
        {children(map)}
      </div>
      <div id="popup">
        <div id="popup-content"></div>
      </div>
    </>
    
  );
};

export default BaseMap;
```

FireIncidentMap.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import BaseMap from "./BaseMap";
import DataLayer from "./DataLayer";
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox} from "@mui/material";

const FireIncidentMap = () => {
    const center = [122.6217542, 11.6978352];
    const zoom = 6;
    const [layerType, setLayerType] = useState(null);
  
    const handleChange = (e) => {
      setLayerType(e.target.checked ? 'fireIncident' : null);
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox checked={layerType === 'fireIncident'} onChange={handleChange} />}
          label="Fire Incident"
        />
        <BaseMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
          {(map) => map && <DataLayer map={map} layerType={layerType} />}
        </BaseMap>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default FireIncidentMap;
```

Comment: Have a look at the example openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html. Do you have `div` element with `id="popup"`?

Comment: I had the div element at the BaseMap.jsx. Please see additional code above.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with React and it's logic I can't help your here any further.